Should npm (and pnpn) create symlinks in the .bin folder in Windows?
When I install packages on my linux laptop I get a node_modules/.bin folder full of symlinks but
on my windows machine I there are no symlinks, only 3 files for each package.
One with .ps1 extension, other with .CMD and another with no extension.
I don't use option --no-bin-links and npm config get bin-links returns true.
What I'm I missing here?
Thanks
